# COM error using Python 32 bit on Windows 10 64 bit

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, pythoncom

I am trying to work with a windows dll from the odoo 9 code.
The code in the python class is:

```
import win32com.client
import pythoncom

Pythoncom.CoInitialize ()
Zk = win32com.client.Dispatch ('zkemkeeper.ZKEM.1')
```

When I run it on Windows 8 (64 bit) it works without problems, but when I run it on Windows 10 (64 bit) as a service, I get the following error in the log file:

```
File "C: \ Python27 \ lib \ site-packages \ win32com \ client \ dynamic.py", line 85, in _GetGoodDispatch
IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance (IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
Com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)
```

I checked Regedit; the dll is registered.

When I install Python 32 bit on that same PC, and run the code from the console directly, it gives me the same error. However, I installed Python 64 bit and ran the same code, and it worked fine.

Could anyone tell me how I could fix this error with odoo as a service? Is there any way to point to the 64-bit python I installed on the PC and not the internal one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add context with

```
clsctx=pythoncom.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER
```

to the args passed to Dispatch.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks! I wrote: `Zk = win32com.client.Dispatch ('zkemkeeper.ZKEM.1', clsctx=pythoncom.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER)`

Answer (score 0):

`t = win32com.client.Dispatch("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")`

It is not working for this .

```
tdc = win32com.client.Dispatch("TDApiOle80.TDConnection",clsctx=pythoncom.CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER)
```

Dispatch
    dispatch,
 `userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)`

Comment: perhaps add a small comment explaining why is this a solution :)